# How to analyze the dependency of the header file in c++

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I know that gcc -MM can get all the non-standard library header files it depends on, and -H gets the indented dependency, but when I use -H, I get the dependency of the system library.

```sh
g++ -MM a.cc
a.o: a.cc a.h b.h
```

```
 g++ -MM a.cc -H
. a.h
.. b.h
... /usr/include/math.h
.... /usr/include/features.h
..... /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h
...... /usr/include/bits/wordsize.h
..... /usr/include/gnu/stubs.h
...... /usr/include/gnu/stubs-64.h
.... /usr/include/bits/huge_val.h
.... /usr/include/bits/huge_valf.h
.... /usr/include/bits/huge_vall.h
..............
```

Comment: May reference the doc: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options.

Comment: I don't think `-MM` and `-H` are supposed to be used together.